# Batch moving files from one folder to multiple folders based on file mask

Tags: windows, batch

I have a folder with more than a hundred thousand (100,000+) pdf files generated by a script that need to be moved to multiple folders based on the file name. The pdf files are all named like this: `YY-nnnnn.pdf` where YY is the year and nnnnn is the file sequence within a year, like this:

```
00-00001.pdf
00-00002.pdf
00-00003.pdf
```

Each year contains about 25,000 files. I have generated the files for four years, I still have 6 years worth of pdfs to be generated.

I need to move these files to the server. The server has the following folder structure:

```
D:.
├───00-00000
├───00-01000
├───00-02000
├───00-03000
├───00-04000
├───00-05000
├───00-06000
├───00-07000
├───00-08000
├───00-09000
├───00-10000
├───00-11000
```

Each year can have up to `YY-25000` folders. The files need to go each into their own folder based on the first five characters, like this:

```
├───00-00000
│       00-00001.pdf
│       00-00002.pdf
│       00-00003.pdf
│       00-00004.pdf
...
│       00-00997.pdf
│       00-00998.pdf
│       00-00999.pdf
│       
├───00-01000
│       00-01000.pdf
│       00-01001.pdf
│       00-01002.pdf
```

I was thinking of using the `RoboCopy` utility but could not figure out how to script it correctly. Perhaps a small script will be required.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution based on [this](https://superuser.com/questions/789278/batch-issue-creating-folders-and-moving-documents?rq=1) question. The batch file to move the files is this:

```
@echo off
    for /f "tokens=*" %%F in ('dir/b/a-d d:\temp\pdfprints\*.pdf') do call :sub1 %%F
    goto :eof

    :sub1
    set name=%1
    move d:\temp\pdfprints\%name% R:\%name:~0,5%000\%name%
```